# vue data function syntax

Tags: javascript, function, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm getting following syntax error when compilling my assets:

```
Syntax Error: SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\dtcburger.com\resources\js\components\stripe\STRIPEform3.vue: Unexpected token, expected ";" (51:12)

  49 |     {
  50 |     stripe:null,
> 51 |     stripePK: stripePK,
     |             ^
  52 |     stripeStyles: stripeStyles,
  53 |     cardNumberElement:null,
  54 |     cardExpiryElement:null,
```

[image]

Here is how my code looks, is it because I used ES syntax for component data?

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the object - wrap your function in parentheses and simply return the object literal:

```
data: () => (
  {
    stripe: null,
    stripePK: stripePK,
    //All your other properties
  }
)
```

Alternatively, use the `return` statement:

```
data: () => {
  return {
    stripe: null,
    stripePK: stripePK
    //All your other properties
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main reason for the error is caused because `{}` is interpreted as a code block and not as an object literal. If you see carefully, there is no red squiggly underline on the first `stripe:null,` property. Because, it is interpreted as a [labeled statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

This doesn't throw an error:

```js
{
  stripe: null
}
```

This throws an error saying `Unexpected token :`

```js
{
  stripe: null,
  stripePK: "stripePK"
}
```

To fix your code, you need to either `return` from the function

```
data: () => {
  return {
    stripe: null,
    stripePK: stripePK,
    ...
  }
}
```

OR, [implicitly return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals) from the arrow function by wrapping the object literal in parentheses:

```
data: () => ({
  stripe: null,
  stripePK: stripePK,
  ...
})
```